# Closed - Duplicate a customized work item to be rehused for others work items Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

**Enviroment:**

Azure DevOps

**Action required:**

To duplicated a custom Work Item to be rehused for others that requires that exact same lyout

**Detailed description:**

For a new Team Project is required a very specific setup, that was not easy to anchieve and needs to be replicated across all the rest of Work Item types like User Stories, Tasks, Fetures and so on and it would consume to much time do it manually (we are system engineer so there is always a better way ;) ) so for that reason is required duplicate the Taylored work item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is not such a feature to duplicate a custom work item tpye in azure devops currently. You may have to manually duplicate the work item types.

You can click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to submit a feature request to microsoft development team. Hope they will consider implementing this feature in the feature sprint.